# Splitting a numpy vector at the nth term

Tags: numpy

I have a numpy vector X which is m by 1. I want to split it to 2 vectors after the nth term i.e 1 - n would be in the first vector and n+1 - m would be in second vector. How would I do this? I couldn't get numpy.split to work.

Comment: Can you provide a small explicit example and the matching expected output(s) for clarity?

Answer (score 0):

Simple indexing schemes would suffice

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> m, n = 8, 3
>>> arr = np.arange(m).reshape(m,1)  + 100
>>> arr
array([[100],
       [101],
       [102],
       [103],
       [104],
       [105],
       [106],
       [107]])
>>> arr1 = arr[:n,:]
>>> arr1
array([[100],
       [101],
       [102]])
>>> arr2 = arr[n:,:]
>>> arr2
array([[103],
       [104],
       [105],
       [106],
       [107]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Make slices with the desired value of n

```
import numpy as np

v = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20])

n = 5
v1 = v[0:n]
v2 = v[n:]
print(v1)
print(v2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10)
N = 4

a1, a2 = np.array_split(a, [N])
```

Output:

```
# a1
array([0, 1, 2, 3])

# a2
array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

##### higher dimensions

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10)[:, None]
N = 4

a1, a2 = np.array_split(a, [N], axis=0)
```

Output:

```
# a1
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3]])
# a2
array([[4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
```